# Filter and sort XML before binding it to a repeater?

Tags: c#, repeater

How I can filter, sort xml before binding it to a repeater?
I have a xml data which I need to filter on the basis of querystring and then sort it before binding it into repeater.

I know how to bind xml with repeater and its working fine too but I am facing problem in filtering based on query string and sorting.

Any help would really be appreciated?

My XML is like this

```
<Categories>   
    <Category>
        <Title>Food<Title>
        <Date>12/1/2009</Date>
        <Duration>12/1/2009-12/1/2011</Duration>
        <Description>Who is hungry</Description>
     <Category>
<Categories>
```

I want to sort by date and duration. I also want to filter by title (based on the querystring).

Comment: I am using C# to implement this

Comment: Add some sample XML and give us an example of what gets filtered. Is the filtration based on an attribute, an element name, a value, etc.? Also let us know which .NET version you're using.

Comment: What will it mean to sort by duration? Sort by the start date, end date, or the total time (two years in your example above)?

Comment: duration mean 2 years...that is 12/1/2011-12/1/2009.So first it sorts on the basis of date and then on this time acc. to you total time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ to XML is probably the way to go here, but if you're stuck in 2.0-land, this will return an `XPathNodeIterator` that provides your filtered and sorted XML:

```
 // xPathFilter is a valid XPath expression
 IEnumerable PrepareXml(XmlReader xmlReader, string xPathFilter) 
 {
     XPathNavigator  navigator  = new XPathDocument(xmlReader).CreateNavigator();

     // Compile is an XPathExpression factory method
     XPathExpression expression = XPathExpression.Compile(xPathFilter);

     // This sorts on the values of the selected nodes
     // You might make an overload to let the caller specify different comparers
     expression.AddSort(".", StringComparer.CurrentCulture);

     return navigator.Select(expression);
 }
```

Note that if you only needed to filter (not sort), you could use the simpler, declarative [`TemplateControl.XPathSelect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2f902wc3.aspx) right in your aspx template (the example in the linked documentation is pretty close to your scenario).

`XPathNodeIterator` implements `IEnumerable`, so you can bind a repeater directly to it. To get values in child nodes, use the [`TemplateControl.XPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.templatecontrol.xpath.aspx) method, like this (you could also get attributes or grand-child nodes, etc., with appropriate XPath expressions):

```
 <ItemTemplate>
 We have <%# XPath("Title") %> available starting on <%# XPath("Date") %>:<br />
 <%# XPath("Description") %>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff its working fine filtering and sorting both but how to bind xpathnodeiterator to repeater? Can you help me with that

Comment: I guess Iterating each node and putting it in some arraylist or datatable can solve the problem.Let me try will post the results

Comment: Howdy AB - I've updated to clarify that you can bind directly to the `XPathNodeIterator`, and added an example demonstrating how to access your nodes' values through it.

Comment: Hi Jeff thanks for your help I tried to implement this but don't know something is wrong. The output that i m getting is rendering like Food Description Date -blank row-- --blank row-- --blank row-- Food Description Date --blank row-- --blank row-- --blank row-- –

Comment: I'd have to see your Repeater template(s) to help you debug it - perhaps it's worth starting another question. (Though I should reiterate, if you're using the .NET Framework 3.5 or higher, from what I've seen this would be easier with LINQ to XML, though I have very little experience with it).

Comment: The `XPath("Food")` in the usage example should probably be `XPath("Title")`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the built-in capabilities of LINQ to XML to handle filtering & sorting. Here is a link to do [complex filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387032.aspx). Here is one that shows how to do simple [sorting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387072.aspx).

Combine the two techniques and instead of binding the control to an XML data source, bind to the resulting collection from the final LINQ to XML processing.

For some good LINQ to XML samples go [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397965.aspx)